# Can't connect to iPhone WiFi debugger on Lion running in VM

Tags: debugging, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, osx-lion

I'm running OSX Lion in VM and have set everything up properly, I can compile fine and run apps fine even on a device and I can connect to the VM Lion via WiFi from both a Windows install, another Mac running OSX Leopard and the host OS so I know it is running on the network.

The phone itself has its debug settings set up correctly for the app, the debugger host IP address it has is the same IP address as the VM OSX Lion install.

Is there a special case with VMs and wifi debugging?

I'm using Mono 2.10.4, mono touch v4.0.5 and MonoDevelop v2.4.2

Comment: Please provide us with the versions of MonoTouch, MonoDevelop and Mono being used. E.g. The latest versions supports (and default to) debugging over USB.

Comment: added. I was actually thinking of just moving onto the latest unstable version of mono touch to see if I could get USB debugging working instead..

Comment: you likely mean MonoTouch 4.0.5 right ? ;-)

Comment: Your tools selection (versions) and process looks fine to me (e.g. USB debugging is not in those versions). Could you edit your question to specify how you checked every item (second paragraph) ?

Comment: If the VM is not involved then it could be the same issue as http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=263 - you should read the details and add youtself to the c.c. list to get updates on its resolution.